# Formatting web page with Back end data

Tags: c#, html, database

I am using Sql database and a table has some fields that have data with html and image tags. I have to read that from the .Net front end code and format the web page accordingly. Can anyone help me figure out how I can do that . Any sample code or any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your page:

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(yourEncodedHtmlFromYouDatabase) %>
```

For more info, read this: [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)